# Braintree - create transaction with money transfer

Tags: braintree

I have a marketplace like rental app. I'm currently deciding between Stripe and Braintree. To create a transaction through Braintree, we use `Transaction.sale()` ([API](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/node)). The equivalent for this in Stripe is `charge`, and when creating the charge there is a field `transfer_data` ([API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-transfer_data)) where we can specify a customer account to transfer part of the money to. Is there an equivalent of this for Braintree (without using Braintree marketplace)?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The only way to transfer to a sub-merchant is using the `merchantAccountId` parameter. There is not a way to transfer funds to a customer account outside of marketplace. New merchants not already integrated with Braintree Marketplace should [contact our Sales team](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact/sales) to get started.